# Windows 8 C#/XAMLhow to clear selection from radio group

Tags: c#, xaml

I'd like to know how to clear the selection from a radio group in my windows 8 app.. I was thinking like this:

```
   RadioButton.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Does anyone know how to do this? thanks.

Comment: While you can clear the selection of a radio button by setting `IsChecked` to false it's not really correct use of radio buttons to have all options deselected. You should really be looking at some other UI elements.

Comment: I suggest a "None of the above" option

Answer (score 2):

Try tracking the specific instance of `RadioButton` that is currently selected using the `Checked` event, and assigning `IsChecked = false` to that instance when you need to clear the group. Yes, it's a pain...

Comment: It's not always necessary to track the current selection, though. For example, `ArbitraryButton.IsChecked = true; ArbitraryButton.IsChecked = false;`

Answer (score 1):

You cant clear a selection of a radio button. If you need the ability to clear the selection consider another control like [CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: a "None of the above" option also does the trick if one wants to keep Radios